# How to check if string ends in date and strip result? - SQL

Tags: sql, string, amazon-redshift, case, sql-like

I'm trying to check whether or not a string ends in a year.

Input:

```
file_paths
wowefnowinf/wefionwe/wefowoi/2012-02-03
weofnweofn/weoew/2022-03-04
ewpfowe/ewopfew
```

Desired Output:

```
wowefnowinf/wefionwe/wefowoi/
weofnweofn/weoew/
ewpfowe/ewopfew
```

I'm having trouble first detecting that the strings themselves end in a date-format. This is my query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 'wowefnowinf/wefionwe/wefowoi/2012-02-03' LIKE '%/####\-##\-##'
 THEN TRUE
 ELSE FALSE END AS result
FROM my_table;
```

I should be getting `true` for this, but my query returns `false`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your database engine? The `LIKE` operator doesn't have anything to do with regular expressions in all the SQL dialects I know.

Comment: Wait but why can't I use `LIKE` like in my query? I know this should also be achievable with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Snowflake you can make use of `regexp_like` and `split_part`:

```sql
with dummy as (
    select 'wowefnowinf/wefionwe/wefowoi/2012-02-03' as file_path
    union all
    select 'weofnweofn/weoew/2022-03-04'
    union all
    select 'ewpfowe/ewopfew'
)
select 
    file_path,
    split_part(file_path, '/', -1) as splitted_file_path,
    regexp_like(splitted_file_path, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]') as ends_with_date,
    iff(ends_with_date, trim(file_path, splitted_file_path), file_path) as trimmed_file_path
from dummy;
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to use `split_path` to trim out the last date instead? Like in my desired output

Comment: SPLIT_PART is available in Redshift, so you should be able to use the same approach as I did and get the desired output

Comment: Sorry, by "trim out" I meant include everything except the last date portion. Basically I want to get the same format as in my desired output

Comment: that is confusing: should the expected output return the string without dates, or return true/false whenever there is a date at the end of the string?

Comment: I've adjusted the query to account for both outputs: the last column now returns the file_path without the date, and the ends_with_date column returns true whenever the last part of the file_path is actually a date.